# invalid date dd/mm/ccyy

Tags: c#, advantage-database-server

I want to use dd/MM/yyyy throughout my .net application, but when i pass

the sql to the .net provider it throughs invalid date error.

I have tried `myconn.DateFormat = 'dd/MM/ccyy'` and this also does not work..

please see details below.. any help will be great. thanks

i have `<globalization culture="en-GB"/>` in my web.config file..

i am using advantage 10, .net 4.0 and advantage .net provider 10

```
String SQL = "Select Top 50 xID, STATUS AS Status, C_DATE "+    
"FROM tbCon WHERE C_DATE > '15/05/2006';";    

AdsConnection myconn = new AdsConnection();

myconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + DataPath +
    ";user ID=" + DBUserID + ";password=" + DBPass + ";" +
    "ServerType= LOCAL | REMOTE;TrimTrailingSpaces=True; ReadOnly=False;";
myconn.Open();
myconn.DateFormat = 'dd/MM/ccyy';
IDataAdapter iData = new AdsDataAdapter(SQL, myconn);
DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
iData.Fill(dSet);
dt = dSet.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid passing the data as a string in the query. Use a parameter and pass an actual DateTime object to assign a value to that parameter. This will solve at the root your formatting problems.